# Need a word for when an event or situation that is very unlikely to happen, happens

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need a word for when an event or situation that is very unlikely to happen, happens. For example, let's say the nerdy kid in school, who is an outcast with no friends, dates the popular girl in school. From a stereotypical view point, the likely hood of a "nerd" to date the popular girl in school is very unlikey, but what if it did happen? Is there a word for this type of scenario?

Comment: Please show us a sample sentence or two that would show how you're hoping to use the word. // If it's good: serendipitous(ly).  Maybe *tail of the distribution*.

Comment: It's something that happens _once in a blue moon_.

Comment: This Q isn't one of them. It has been asked here numerous times before. Search for *black swan* to find several examples.

Answer (score 0):

**[Uncommon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncommon#synonyms)** fits

> not ordinarily encountered

Answer (score 0):

Try "black swan":

> **black swan** *n*
>   2. a phenomenon that occurs even though it had been thought to be impossible
>   [*sense 2 from the fact all swans were thought to be white until black swans were discovered in Australia*]
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/black+swan)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Such an unlikely thing would be an *anomaly* and its occurrence would be ***anomalous***. Give him credit. That nerdy kid just kept on swinging.

Answer (score 0):

That's called *fluke*.

> **Fluke (noun and verb):** 
>   An unlikely chance occurrence, especially a surprising piece of luck.
>
> Example: Their victory was a bit of a fluke.

— [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fluke)

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is ***unexpectedly***, which *lexico* defines as:

> In a way that was not expected or regarded as likely

Other top contenders with similar but not precisely the same meaning would be ***peculiarly*** and ***bizzarely***.

> Unexpectedly/Peculiarly/Bizzarely, the nerdiest kid in school was dating the head cheerleader.